# Spring Kafka Accumulator Use Case

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am developing a SpringBoot application which consumes events from a Kafka (broker version is 2.6) input topic and produce an event into an output topic.

In order to respect some business constraints the component should wait to have at least X messages (which is a batch size) or until a timeout expired. In conclusion, it should act like an accumulator.
Further, another mandatory requirement is to respect exactly-once semantic.

The first solution I approached was to maintain events in-memory until constraints are satisfied and then publish output messages. In order to implement an at least-once semantic I used manual_immediate ack mode and I stored latest ack for each partition in-memory and acknowledge after processing ended (it may cause duplicates in race conditions but it is acceptable).

In order to increase reliability I enforced upstream transactionality and set read_committed mode on listener.

I was wondering wheter it is a correct approach or if there is any suitable solution like batch_mode listener.
On a first look it is wonderful, but it seems not to allow accumulating on number of records, but rather on data size in bytes.

Thanks in advance,
G.

Comment: `>but it seems not to allow accumulating on number of records, but rather on data size in bytes.` That is correct; it's a limitation of the kafka-clients.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell for your answer. Do you have any suggestion on a proper solution for this use case?

Comment: There is none; unless your messages are equal size and you can figure out how large to set `fetch.min.bytes`.